# in linux how to make a batch file executable from my ada program by spawning chmod 777 mem.bat

Tags: linux, ada

## spawning a linux command line from an ada program

HI,
I need to spawn a linux command line from an ada program
the command line is chmod 777 mem.bat
(it makes mem.bat executable)
from the same ada program
where mem.bat is the batch file i need to run just after the creation of mem.bat
Just created by the said ada program.
here are the main code lines to achieve that goal

```
-- I use something like  these
 
with Gnat.Os_Lib;
use Gnat.Os_Lib;
Command_1 : constant String := "chmod 777 mem.bat";
Args := Argument_String_To_List(Command_1);
Spawn(Program_Name => Args(Args'First).all,
Args         => Args(Args'First + 1 .. Args'Last),
Success      => Success);
-- but it does not do the job
-- help will be appreciated

-- thanks
```

Comment: You could instead spawn `call` and pass `mem.bat` as an argument.

Comment: From spec: For maximum portability, use a full path name for the `Program_Name` argument.

Comment: there is the separate question of what use a Windows ".bat" file is on a Linux system... there may be an XY problem here.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure if using `Spawn` directly is the best way forward here. I would choose one of the following three alternatives for achieving your goal:

#### 1. Use `GNAT.OS_Lib.Set_Executable`

If all you want is to make the file executable, then use `GNAT.OS_Lib.Set_Executable`:

**main_v1.adb**

```
with GNAT.OS_Lib; use GNAT.OS_Lib;

procedure Main_v1 is
   Name : constant String := "mem.bat";
   
begin   
   Set_Executable (Name, Mode => S_Owner);
   Set_Executable (Name, Mode => S_Group);
   Set_Executable (Name, Mode => S_Others);   
   
end Main_v1;
```

**output**

```
$ touch mem.bat; ll mem.bat
-rw-rw-r--. 1 deedee deedee 0 May  9 21:44 mem.bat
$ ./main_v1; ll mem.bat
-rwxrwxr-x. 1 deedee deedee 0 May  9 21:44 mem.bat
```

#### 2. Use `GNAT.Expect`

`GNAT.Expect` is included in the GNAT standard library. An example on its use was already shown in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56586269/10975520) SO answer. You can rework the example for your particular problem.

**main_v2.adb**

```
with Ada.Text_IO;
with GNAT.Expect;

procedure Main_v2 is

   Command    : constant String := "chmod";
   Argument_1 : aliased String  := "777";
   Argument_2 : aliased String  := "mem.bat";
   Input      : constant String := "";
   Status     : aliased Integer := 0;

   --  Execute the command and retrieve the output.

   Output : String :=
              GNAT.Expect.Get_Command_Output
                (Command    => Command,
                 Arguments  => (1 => Argument_1'Unchecked_Access,
                                2 => Argument_2'Unchecked_Access),
                 Input      => Input,
                 Status     => Status'Access,
                 Err_To_Out => True);

   --  NOTE: Cheating with Unchecked_Access, OK for demo. You may want
   --        to properly new and Free these strings (see Argument_List
   --        type in package GNAT.OS_Lib).

begin
   if Status /= 0 then
      Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line ("chmod failed: " & Output);
   end if;
   
end Main_v2;
```

**output**

```
$ touch mem.bat && ll mem.bat 
-rw-rw-r--. 1 deedee deedee 0 May  9 21:15 mem.bat
$ ./main_v2 && ll mem.bat
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 deedee deedee 0 May  9 21:15 mem.bat
```

#### 3. Use Florist

As `chmod` is a POSIX function, you could also consider to use the Florist library. The Florist library is readily available in distributions like Debian ([libflorist](https://packages.debian.org/bullseye/libflorist2020)), in [Alire](https://github.com/alire-project/alire-index/blob/stable-1.1/index/fl/florist/florist-external.toml) (only when running on Debian or Ubuntu), or otherwise as source from [this](https://github.com/AdaCore/florist) repository on GitHub provided by AdaCore.

**main_v3.adb**

```
with POSIX.Files;
with POSIX.Permissions;

procedure Main_v3 is
   use POSIX.Permissions;
   
   New_Permissions : constant POSIX.Permissions.Permission_Set :=
     (Owner_Read     => True,
      Owner_Write    => True,
      Owner_Execute  => True,
      Group_Read     => True,
      Group_Write    => True,
      Group_Execute  => True,
      Others_Read    => True,
      Others_Write   => True,
      Others_Execute => True,
      others         => False);
   
begin
   POSIX.Files.Change_Permissions
     (Pathname   => "mem.bat",
      Permission => New_Permissions);
   
end Main_v3;
```

**output**

```
$ touch mem.bat && ll mem.bat 
-rw-rw-r--. 1 deedee deedee 0 May  9 21:16 mem.bat
$ ./main_v3 && ll mem.bat
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 deedee deedee 0 May  9 21:16 mem.bat
```

#### 4. Importing `chmod` as system call

You can also just import the `chmod` directly as a system call. See also `man 3p chmod` (or [here](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/chmod.3p.html)) for its C signature. Ada has excellent facilities to import C programs as shown in the example below.

**main_v4.adb**

```
with Ada.Text_IO;
with Interfaces.C;
with GNAT.OS_Lib;

procedure Main_v4 is

   package C renames Interfaces.C;
   use type C.int;  --  Make operators of C.int (like "<") directly visible.
   
   subtype mode_t is C.unsigned;
      
   function chmod (path : C.char_array; mode : mode_t) return C.int
     with Import, Convention => C;
   
   path : aliased C.char_array := C.To_C ("mem.bat");
   
   result : C.int;
   
begin  
   result := chmod (path, 8#777#);   --  777 as octal number (base-8)
   if result < 0 then
      Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line ("chmod failed: " & GNAT.OS_Lib.Errno_Message);
   end if;
   
end Main_v4;
```

**output**

```
$ touch mem.bat && ll mem.bat 
-rw-rw-r--. 1 deedee deedee 0 May  9 21:17 mem.bat
$ ./main_v4 && ll mem.bat
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 deedee deedee 0 May  9 21:17 mem.bat
```